# arrays in $.ajax jquery and then sends it to a php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Set the data text  
    var dataText = "
    { 
        name: 'John',
        time: '2pm' 
     }";  

    alert(dataText);
    // Create the AJAX request  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",                    // Using the POST method  
        url: "/ajax/analytics/push",      // The file to call  
        data: dataText,                  // Our data to pass  
        success: function() {            // What to do on success  
             alert("Data Loaded: " + dataText);
        }  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

hello im still learning ajax. how can we push a array of $_POST?

1.im trying to do something like

```
var dataText['name'] = 'Jhon';
var dataText['time] = '2pm';
```

then somehow turns it into

```
$_POST['name'] = 'Jhon';
$_POST['time'] = '2pm';
```

then send it to the url..

2.is there a way to debug this ? what im doing now is im writing

```
        # somehow doesnt work becouse its not auto refresh when the ajax sends a post
    var_dump($_POST);

        # ok heres how i debug it right now.
    ob_start();
    // write content
    $content = $_POST;
    ob_end_clean();
    file_put_contents('CACHE',$content);
```

in to a file, i hope there is a better solution for this..

Thankyou for looking in.
Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing.  You seem to be building JSON manually (and not doing it correctly) and then passing that (in the JSON-serialised string form) to your file.  You then seem to expect it to be parsed by PHP automatically.

It would be better to send it as key-value pairs.  You can let jQuery do this for you if you pass in an object.  This won't look much different to your existing code:

```
var dataText = 
{ 
    name: 'John',
    time: '2pm' 
};
```

Note that I have removed the double quotes.  This is primarily because it is illegal to have a JS string covering more than one line without escaping the line breaks.  It is also because you want the object to pass into your `$.ajax` call.

These should be available as `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['time']` now.

Comment: it returns an object. ah i see. so jquery can do that, passing arrays to posts. i was wondering about that. how about debug it ? i mean how can you see whats received on the php page?

Comment: @Adam It doesn't *return* an object -- it takes an object as a parameter.  You should be able to debug it with something like `file_put_contents('CACHE', var_export($_POST, true))`. Note that you'll have to turn output buffering off for this to work.

Comment: works!. anyway the return is an array array (
  'name' => 'John',
  'time' => '2pm',
) . thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('CACHE',serialize($content));
```

or

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) $content .= $k .'='.$v;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Set the data text  
    var dataText = 
    { 
        name: 'John',
        time: '2pm' 
     };  

    alert(dataText);
    // Create the AJAX request  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",                    // Using the POST method  
        url: "/ajax/analytics/push",      // The file to call  
        data: dataText,                  // Our data to pass  
        success: function() {            // What to do on success  
             alert("Data Loaded: " + dataText);
        }  
    });  
});
```

```
        # ok heres how i debug it right now.
    ob_start();

     # somehow doesnt work becouse its not auto refresh when the ajax sends a post
    var_dump($_POST);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    file_put_contents('CACHE',$content);
```